# Calling a write function of a contract will deploy a new contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, ethereumjs

I'm calling a function that will write information to contract, and MetaMask will list it as a 'Contract Deployment'. It is on the Rinkeby testnet. But if I run it locally using Truffle/Ganache, it will list it as a 'Contract Call', as opposed to a 'Contract Creation'.

Here is my code:

```
this.contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractAddress)

let accounts = web3.eth.getAccounts()
... 
let contractFunctionData = this.contract.methods.contractFunction(params).encodeABI()
web3.eth.sendTransaction({ 
  from: accounts[0],
  data: contractFunctionData
}, function(err, result) {
  if(!err)
    console.log(result)
})
```

when it logs `result` it returns the address of the new contract created.

This only happens with write functions. Read functions work as expected and return the right output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is missing a `to` address. If you send a transaction to address `0` (the default), it creates a new contract. Adding `to: contractAddress` should work.

BTW, you might also consider just letting the contract instance do the work rather than using `web3.eth.sendTransaction` directly:

```
this.contract.methods.contractFunction(params).send()
```

This would ensure that the right `data` and `to` address are used.

Comment: I changed my code according to what you suggested and it worked, with MetaMask listing it as a 'transaction' instead of a 'contract creation'! The only this is I was getting a TypeError when I tried to use `.sendTransaction()', but when I tried using `.send()` it worked.

Comment: My mistake! Edited to have `.send()` instead.